# Error adding new page Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHifF.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYJFS.png)

I'm trying to add some simple page to existing project. I can't make it work using function (Other pages did so) and const =()=>. I did all component, css and router things. What can be the problem?

Comment: Please beware using screenshots where not necessary. Use ``` to show your code and >ERROR to show your error.

Comment: Sorry, we can't help address issues with code we can't see. Please edit the post to include a complete [mcve] enough to reproduce the issue ourselves. The post should include formatted and readable code snippets, and the complete error message and any code stacktraces.

Comment: The file name should be in Pascal's case in react like in your case it should be Personal. And Please try to provide with code, not with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is error of importing. First of all start your component with capital letter and then do:

The exporting component

```js
export function Hello (){
    return ()
}
export default Hello
```

The importing component

```js
import Hello from "./Hello"
// OR
import { Hello } from "./Hello"
```